# Transactional replication w/ immediate update - Publisher triggers are firing on immediate update, or not replicating their modifications

Tags: sql-server

I have a publisher and multiple subscribers configured for transactional replication with immediate update.  I have two replicated tables, MyTable and MyTableHistory.  I have a "not for replication" trigger that captures the history of changes to MyTable and places them in the MyTableHistory table.  Here is my problem:

**If I try to place the trigger ONLY on the publisher:**
When a user updates MyTable on the subscriber, the record is immediately created on the publisher via a distributed transaction and Microsoft's stored procedures and triggers as intended by the "immediate update" type replication.  This fires the trigger on the publisher which creates the history record on the publisher as expected.  HOWEVER, the history record just created by the trigger is not replicated back out to the subscriber.  I'm guessing it's a side effect of them preventing replicating already replicated records back to the subscriber that originated them.

**If I try to place the trigger on BOTH the publisher and subscribers:**
When a user updates MyTable on the subscriber, the record is immediately created on the publisher which fires the trigger and results in a duplicate history record.  No matter what I've tried, I cannot figure out how to get the trigger to detect that the record is being modified by replication's "immediate update" and so it should abort.  I've tried "not for replication" and "sp_check_for_sync_trigger", but I learned that these weren't intended to detect what I'm looking for.

I think the first of the two options above are preferred, but at this point, I'm open to any approach that will make one of the two options above work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get an answer here, as Updatable Subscriptions for Transactional Replication were deprecated with SQL 2008.  Making you probably now one of the world's foremost experts on them :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to place the triggers on both publisher and subscribers, and include the following code in the trigger to bail under certain conditions to avoid the trigger from firing during replication maintenance.  It requires the following three approaches:

1. not for replication trigger option - Prevents the subscriber trigger from firing
   when a record is replicated from the publisher to subscribers
2. spGetLastCommand - This is a signed stored procedure I created with
   view server state permission.  It returns the last command so we can
   check if it was the replication stored procedure run on the
   publisher so we can prevent the publisher trigger from firing when
   the subscriber changes cause an immediate update to the publisher.
3. sp_check_for_sync_trigger - This code prevents the trigger from
   firing when an update statement is issued while the replication
   stored procedures are trying to update the ms_repl_tran column.

Hope that helps someone.  But probably not since we're the last ones on the planet using this type of replication ;)

```
declare @last_command nvarchar(512)
exec master..spGetLastCommand @last_command output
if @last_command like '%sp_MSsync_%_MyTable_1%' begin
    return
end

declare @table_id int = object_id('MyTable')
declare @trigger_op varchar(max)
declare @retcode int
exec @retcode = sp_check_for_sync_trigger @table_id, @trigger_op output, @fonpublisher=1
if @retcode = 1 begin
    return
end
exec @retcode = sp_check_for_sync_trigger @table_id, @trigger_op output, @fonpublisher=0
if @retcode = 1 begin
    return
end";
```